# openpyxl, how to read cell type

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have an xlsx data file and I want to know types of cells.
I wrote this code:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('data.xlsx', data_only=True)
list = wb['list']

val1 = list.cell(row=1, column=1).value
val2 = list.cell(row=2, column=1).value

print "val1", val1, type(val1)
print "val2", val2, type(val2)
```

But the result is:

```
val1 21:59:44 <type 'datetime.time'>
val2 17:04:50 <type 'unicode'>
```

What is proper way to load cells types.

The source of sample and data file is here:
https://github.com/ombschervister/openpyxl_test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [this bug report](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/612) openpyxl is behaving as expected: cell A2 contains a string.

Comment: Ok, Just when I open program 'Excel', I see Time format. So maybe there is a way to get this information, on which Excel determines the format of the cell?

Comment: `ws['A2'].number_format` but you can't rely on this. You could have the same format for "Mary had a little lamb". openpyxl does support type guessing but we strongly advise against using it.